# 'title' tag on the header is missing in TYPO3 template

Tags: html, typo3, typo3-9.x, html-title

I set up a website using TYPO3 v9.5.9 and I can't find the `<title>` tag on the HTML source.

How can I insert the current page `<title>` automatically into the header?

Here is how my header is currently displayed:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<base href="/" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="generator" content="TYPO3 CMS" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="typo3conf/ext/frontend_editing/Resources/Public/Css/frontend_editing.css?1562352305" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="typo3/sysext/backend/Resources/Public/Css/backend.css?1566293615" media="all" />
```

Comment: The `<title>` tag should be automatically included; please check your TypoScript Setup; for example if you have `config.noPageTitle = 1` or `page.config.noPageTitle = 1`

Comment: I checked my TS and I have `config.noPageTitle = 2`

Comment: That means it is not printed at all https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Setup/Config/Index.html?highlight=config#nopagetitle

Comment: Screenshot of my page web : https://imgur.com/f9OqP8Z

Comment: according to the documentation, `config.noPageTitle = 2` means that the `<title>` tag is omitted on the page; you could remove that line to have the title printed again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution solved my problem. It was necessary to remove the line :

`config.noPageTitle = 2`

Thanks to @Riccardo De Contardi for this solution.